# Product of $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\ldots (x-k+1)$

Tags: notation

I was working on a formula, and along the way, I came across this product:$$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\ldots(x-k+1)\tag1$$
This is just a quick question, but

> **Question:** Is there a shorthand notation for $(1)$? I mean, besides writing all of the terms out.

An example would be something like the sigma notation $\sum$ meaning adding, or $\prod$ meaning the product of the terms.

I feel like there *is* a notation for $(1)$, but I just don't know it. Any suggestions?

Comment: This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) may be useful.

Comment: Your title does not match the expression in the body of your question. Additionally, the "$+1$" in the expression does not make sense to me. I think you mean to write $$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)...(x-k)$$

Comment: @pseudoeuclidean No, I meant $(x-k+1)$. For example, let's let $c_{\text{something}}:=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\ldots$. If that 'something'$=3$, then it would be$$c_3=(x-1)(x-2)$$If it was $4$, then the product would be$$c_4=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$$

Comment: @angryavian So close! We're missing the $x$ term... Although, we *could* have$$\dfrac {(x)_k}x$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this notion in Mathematics is called a *falling factorial* ([more info from MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html)). The general notation is
$$
(x)_n = x(x-1) \ldots (x-(n-1)),
$$
so your expression is
$$
(x-1) \times \ldots \times (x-k+1) = (x-1) \times \ldots \times (x-(k-1)) = (x-1)_{k-1}
$$

Comment: $(x)_n$ is usually denoted by $x^{\underline n}$ to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @HenryW. i now recall this notation from my combinatorics class, but can you please refresh my memory -- what is the possible ambiguity with $(x)_n$? Sequences are denoted $(x_n)$, is there something else?

Comment: I think if the expression in the bracket is simple (e.g. a single number) there is no confusion, but for more complex equations it can be misinterpreted as index notation.

Answer (score 6):

If falling powers aren't common enough, you could write it fairly economically as
$$\frac{(x-1)!}{(x-k)!}$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. We can write it as $$\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(x-i).$$

Answer (score 2):

If we multiply the expression by $x$ and divide by $k!$ we have,

$$\frac{x(x-1)....(x-k+1)}{k!}$$

This is precisely ${x \choose k}$, so your product can be rewritten as,

$$k! {x \choose k} \frac{1}{x}$$

After reversing the original operations performed.

If you don't like the $x$ in the denominator here is another solution.

Replace $x$ by $x+1$ in the expression to get,

$$x(x-1).....(x-(k-1)+1)$$

Again we recognize this as,

$$(k-1)! {x+1-1 \choose k-1}$$

Then we replace $x+1$ by $x$ to reverse what we just did,

So the expression is

$$=(k-1)!{x-1 \choose k-1}$$